# Image related queries in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, android-image

I am about to begin a project in PhoneGap for Android, Windows Mobile and BlackBerry.

There are some question I have:

1. where would I place Android images? In Titanium Studio we had folders for ldpi/mdpi/hdpi images inside `android/image/` folder, but in PhoneGap there isn't such a folder.
2. how do I create a button from JavaScript with it's size being decided by the image we assign it?

In my CSS:

```
.deleteButton { 
    background-color:Transparent;
    background-image:url('../img/button_delete.png');
    width:64px;
    height:32px;
}
```

My JavaScript code to create button:

```
var element4 = document.createElement("input");
element4.type = "button";
element4.setAttribute("onclick","deleteSelectedRow(this)");
element4.className = "deleteButton";
cell4.appendChild(element4);
```

Answer (score 0):

you put the images in the www folder, probably like www/img or smthng like that.  for the second question, there are different ways i think, you can specify the class img selector as width 100% and height auto i think.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. **@images**, I tried making folders (drawable-mdpi and res-mdpi) but neither worked. **@img dimensions** , how can I do that? I haven't worked in HTML in more than a year, so I will need pointers. :)